# Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

Tags: mysql

I am inserting values in my table and I'am stuck in a Date datatype problem

```
Insert into EMP_1 
(
    EMP_NUM, 
    EMP_LNAME,
    EMP_FNAME,
    EMP_INITIAL, 
    EMP_HIREDATE, 
    JOB_CODE
)
Values 
(
    101, 
    'News', 
    'John', 
    'G', 
    08-11-00, 
    502
);
```

this is the execution result

> Operand type clash: int is incompatible with date

Comment: Put 08-11-00 with `'08-11-00'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the date in `'` or it will treat it as a `integer` value and its expecting a date.

```
Insert into  EMP_1 (EMP_NUM, EMP_LNAME,EMP_FNAME,EMP_INITIAL, EMP_HIREDATE, JOB_CODE)
Values (101, 'News', 'John', 'G', '08-11-00', 502);
```

Answer (score 0):

Always make use of quotes

Insert into EMP_1 (EMP_NUM,EMP_LNAME,EMP_FNAME,EMP_INITIAL,EMP_HIREDATE,JOB_CODE) Values ('101','News','John','G','08-11-00','502');

or you can write NOW() or CURDATE()function

Insert into EMP_1 (EMP_NUM,EMP_LNAME,EMP_FNAME,EMP_INITIAL,EMP_HIREDATE,JOB_CODE) Values ('101','News','John','G',NOW(),'502');